# Read multiple text files to 2D numpy array in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 10 txt files. Each of them with strings.

```
A.txt: "This is a cat"
B.txt: "This is a dog"
.
.
J.txt: "This is an ant"
```

I want to read these multiple files and put it in 2D array.

```
[['This', 'is', 'a', 'cat'],['This', 'is', 'a', 'dog']....['This', 'is', 'an', 'ant']]

from glob import glob
import numpy as np
for filename in glob('*.txt'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype=str)
```

It's not working the way I want. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just generating different numpy arrays for each text file and not saving any of them. How about add each file to a list like so and convert to numpy later?

```
data = []

for filename in glob('*.txt'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data.append(f.read().split())

data = np.array(data)
```

Comment: Can you just explain how does it line help? - data.append(f.read().split())

Comment: it is because we are keeping a list of all of the text in the files. `f.read().split()` would produce `['This', 'is', 'a', 'cat']` for  a file containing 'This is a cat' and so appending that to data gives the desired 2d array